# How can I prompt user many time for different filenames using a for loop?

Tags: c++, char, fstream

I'm trying to open and read user input files with my C++ program.

My program has 2 functions; `Open_Read()` and `Enter_Filename()`.

The `Enter_Filename` asks the user to enter input filenames (from 1 to 4).

The function `Open_Read` opens and reads the content of the file and displays it.

When `nb = 1` (1 <= nb <=4) the program works, but from `nb >=2` the program cannot open file (or cannot find the file).

Can someone help me find the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using Namespace std;

void Enter_Filename(const int& m, int& nb, char name[], double yy[], double xx[]);
void Open_Read(ifstream&, char filename[], char name[], double yy[], double xx[], int &n, double &sd, char set1[]);

double y[256], x[256];

int main()
{ 
    ifstream in;
    char filename[7];
    char name[7];
    char set1[20];
    double yy[4];
    double xx[4];
        int n = 0;
    double sd = 0;
        int nb;
    int m = 4;

    Enter_Filename(m, nb, filename, &yy[4], &xx[4]);

for (int i = 1; i <= nb; i++)
    {
        Open_Read(in, &filename[i], &name[i], &yy[i], &xx[i], n, sd, &set1[i]);
    }

    cout << "\n";
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Here the function `Enter_Filename`:

```
  void Enter_Filename(const int& m, int& nb, char name[], double yy[], double xx[])
 {
     cout << "Please Enter the number of articles (1 <= nb <= 4)\n"
     "Nb =";
     cin >> nb;

     if (nb <= m)
     {
        for (int j = 1; j <= nb; j++)
        {
            cout << j << ".Article (e.g. input.txt, input1.txt...) =";
            cin >> &name[j];
            cout << "yy(" << j << ") =";
            cin >> yy[j];
            cout << "xx(" << j << ") =";
            cin >> xx[j];
        }
     }
 }
```

And the function `Open_Read`:

```
void Open_Read(ifstream&, char filename[], char name[], double yy[], double xx[], int& n, double &sd, char set1[])
{

    ifstream inf;

    //cout << "Enter the file name to be opened: ";

    //cin >> fileName;

    inf.open(filename, ios::in);

    if (inf.fail())
    {
        cout << "Opening " << filename << " file for reading\n";
        cout << "---------------------------------------\n";
        cout << "The " << filename << " file could not be opened!\n";
        cout << "Possible errors:\n";
        cout << "1. The file does not exist.\n";
        cout << "2. The path was not found.\n";
        exit(1); 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "fileName:" << filename << endl;
        inf >> name >> set1;
        inf.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        inf >> n >> sd;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            inf >> y[i] >> x[i];

            printf("%3i: %10.3f %10.3f\n", i, y[i], x[i]);

        }

        y[0] = *yy;
        x[0] = x[0] + *xx;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            y[i] = y[i - 1] + y[i];
            x[i] = x[i] + *xx;
        }
    }

    inf.close();

    cout << "NAME:" << name << endl;
    cout << "SetID:" << set1 << endl;
    cout << "N =" << n << endl;
    cout << "SubD =" << sd << endl;

    if (inf.fail())
    {
        cout << "\nThe file " << filename << " could not be closed!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    return;
}
```

I use two files: `input.txt` and `input1.txt`:

```
 input.txt

 INPUT.TXT
 1S12-111-433-3245 K
   5         12.0000
      0.000          12.290
      1.840           0.170
      1.480           6.190
      1.220          17.100 
      1.040          25.000


 input1.txt

 INPUT1.TXT
 1S12-111-533-3245 P
   3       12.0000
      .000           11.780
     0.150           34.820
     1.840           24.810
```

Comment: You should improve your indentation.

Comment: `char filename[7];` can't hold multiple filenames. You probably meant to have something like `std::string filename[7];`

Comment: Your code indentation was really awful. You can't be a good programmer, if you are not able to do such elementary thing like the code indentation and style.

Comment: @mch thanks, i will do it.

Comment: @Dawid Ferenczy there is always a beginning to everything

Comment: `Function1()` is a very bad name for _any_ function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working version of your application:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iosfwd>


using namespace std;
void Enter_Filename(const int& m, int& nb, char name[], double yy[], double xx[], int j);
void Open_Read(ifstream&, char filename[], char name[], double yy[], double xx[], int &n, double &sd, char set1[]);

double y[256], x[256];

int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    char filename[4][10];

    char name[7];
    char set1[20];
    double yy[4];
    double xx[4];
    int n = 0;
    double sd = 0;
    int nb;
    int m = 4;

    cout << "Please Enter the number of articles (1 <= nb <= 4)\n"
        "Nb =";
    cin >> nb;

    if (nb <= m)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nb; j++)
        {
            Enter_Filename(m, nb, filename[j], &yy[4], &xx[4], j);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
    {
        Open_Read(in, filename[i], &name[i], &yy[i], &xx[i], n, sd, &set1[i]);
    }

    cout << "\n";
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}


void Enter_Filename(const int& m, int& nb, char name[], double yy[], double xx[], int j)
{

            cout << j << ".Article (e.g. input.txt, input1.txt...) =";
            cin >> &name[0];
            cout << "yy(" << j << ") =";
            cin >> yy[j];
            cout << "xx(" << j << ") =";
            cin >> xx[j];

}





void Open_Read(ifstream&, char filenames[], char name[], double yy[], double xx[], int& n, double &sd, char set1[])
{

    ifstream inf;

    //cout << "Enter the file name to be opened: ";

    //cin >> fileName;
    char filename[11];
    memcpy(filename, filenames, 11);
    filename[10] = '\0';

    inf.open(filename, ios::in);

    if (inf.fail())
    {
        cout << "Opening " << filename << " file for reading\n";
        cout << "---------------------------------------\n";
        cout << "The " << filename << " file could not be opened!\n";
        cout << "Possible errors:\n";
        cout << "1. The file does not exist.\n";
        cout << "2. The path was not found.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "fileName:" << filename << endl;
        inf >> name >> set1;
        inf.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        inf >> n >> sd;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            inf >> y[i] >> x[i];

            printf("%3i: %10.3f %10.3f\n", i, y[i], x[i]);

        }

        y[0] = *yy;
        x[0] = x[0] + *xx;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            y[i] = y[i - 1] + y[i];
            x[i] = x[i] + *xx;
        }
    }

    inf.close();

    cout << "NAME:" << name << endl;
    cout << "SetID:" << set1 << endl;
    cout << "N =" << n << endl;
    cout << "SubD =" << sd << endl;

    if (inf.fail())
    {
        cout << "\nThe file " << filename << " could not be closed!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    return;
}
```

I did not control what was coming out from your calculations, i only ensured that now it opens your  files

Comment: i think you' re right, but  with char filename[4][7] i have some difficulties to open a file using fstream

Comment: if 'filename'  in    inf.open(filename, ios::in);    needs to be a char[] , then there will be no problems

Comment: inf.open(filename, ios::in) ;                                                                         i tried several times but it did not work , i have the error                  c2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [][7] '  to  ' const wchar_t*'

Comment: use Filename.c_str() instead of Filename in the call of ifstream::open

Comment: filename.c_str() does not work with char filename[4][7], not even with      string filename[4][7]. But with string filename only

Comment: I edited the post with a working version of your code.

Comment: Good, can you please up my answer +1. tnx

Comment: it's done, it will appear when I reach 15 reputations